# Is there a way that saving file in VS code triggers the return in Vim normal mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I start using the VSCodeVim plugin in VS Code.

I regularly save my file with Cmd-S (in Mac).

Following the philosophy of Practical Vim book, I consider this save point moment as a break in my thinking process. It would be cool if when I type Cmd-S, Vim returns in Normal mode.

Is there a way ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

In `keybindings.json`, add :

```
  {
    "key": "cmd+s",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "sequence": [
        "workbench.action.files.save",
        "extension.vim_escape"
      ]
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && vim.mode != 'Normal'"
  }
```

We need to add an extra extension, because VS Code doesn't handle internally to trigger multiple commands. So add [`multi-command`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension.

Comment: Great question & solution!  Thanks to both.  This has always bothered me.